# How to make components resize at run time as the user resize the form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am developing a new application using delphi. I have a form called MainForm. The MainForm has 3 panels: Panel1 , Panel2 and Panel 3. The panels are inserted in order from top of the form to the bottom of the form. Panel1 Align property is set to alTop and Panel3 Align property is set to alBottom. Panel 2 align property is set to alClient. I have a DBGrid on the Panel2.

The problem is when the users resize the form at the runtime the DBGrid size is not affected. When I change the order of panel 2 and panel 3 the DBGrid's size changes as the user changes the size of the form.

I was wondering if it is possible to have the panel 2 at the middle of the form and also make the DBGrid to change as the user change the size of form?

Comment: If you can't make it with align props, handle the OnResize event of the panels' container.

Comment: @Tom That's the only plausible explanation and so should be the answer

Answer (score 7):

Works fine for me in Delphi 7. You did not say so, but I assume you set `DBGrid.Align` property to `alClient`, didn't you?
Alternatively to setting `DBGrid.Align` property, you can set `DBGrid.Anchors` to `[akLeft,akTop,akRight,akBottom]` (that is all four are `true`).

---

Edit after comments regarding two DBGrids

If you want the two DBGrids to both resize with the form, then I suggest you skip `Panel3`, place both DBGrids on `Panel2` (unaligned) and add the following OnResize event to the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.Left := 0;
  DBGrid1.Width := Panel2.Width -1;
  DBGrid1.Top := 0;
  DBGrid1.Height := Panel2.Height div 2-1;
  DBGrid2.Left := 0;
  DBGrid2.Width := Panel2.Width -1;
  DBGrid2.Top    := Panel2.Height div 2;
  DBGrid2.Height := Panel2.Height div 2-1;
end;
```

With the above, the height of the grids are equally sized vertically as the form is resized.

Comment: Yes I did the dbgrid.align property to alClient. But it just works fine when there is 1 DBGrid component on the form. If there is a dbgrid on panel2 and a dbgrid on panel3 it wont work! Although all the dbgrids align property is set to alClient on each panel

Comment: You mentioned only one DBGrid in your question. However, the grid on `Panel2` changes according to form size changes, when the `DBGrid.Align` is set to `alClient`, regardless what components you have on `Panel3`. Of course, `Panel3` doesn't change on form resizing because it's `Align` property is `alBottom`. You need to be more specific about what 'wont work'.

Comment: @PNS: details like this are important for this sort of questions, you can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31097442/edit) your original question...

Comment: @PNS This is why you have to state the actual problem. A simple MCVE, say a. dfm file, would have sufficed. Waiting until your question is answered before explaining what your problem is is highly counter productive and frustrating for us. Please learn from this.

Comment: DavidHeffernan @Tom Thank you for your help and sorry for presenting the question in bad manner. It worked by your solution.

Comment: @PNS I reviewed my old answers and noticed that you said in previous comment that my solution worked but you havent marked it as correct (see the check mark on the left, under the votes).